# How to load dependencies (external libraries) for Apache2 modules?

Tags: c++, c, apache2, shared-libraries, apache-modules

I'm developing an Apache2 module that requires and external library. I'm able to build the module and generate the DSO (.so file). However, whenever the server tries to load the module, I get `undefined symbol` errors and the server fails to start.

I think it is because the shared object of the library is not being loaded. But I'm not sure how I can tell Apache to load it (or where to find it). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Answering myself here!

Need to add a `LoadFile` directive in the .load file of the module before `LoadModule`.

```
LoadFile /usr/lib/xx.so
LoadModule yy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_yy.so
```

I should note that apparently the order is important here and the dependencies should be loaded first before the Apache2 module itself.